# How to echo MySQL results in inverse order?

Tags: php, mysql, html, sql, database

```
$result3=mysql_query("select * from $mail"); 

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result3)) { 
    if($row['status']!=NULL) {   
        echo $row['status'];
        echo $row['date'];
        echo $row['time'];
    }
}
```

i want that the last field in the database should be displayed first. How to implement this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * from $mail ORDER BY `date` DESC");
```

Never do yourself what the database can do for you.

If, for whatever weird reason, you actually want to *traverse the result set* in reverse order, you'll have to use [`mysql_data_seek`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php), starting at `mysql_num_rows() - 1` and decrementing the pointer after each call to `mysql_fetch_array`.

Answer (score 2):

Use an `ORDER BY` clause in your query so that the results come in the order you want to display them.

Without an `ORDER BY`, there is no guarantee about what order the data will come in, so "reversing" that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Either user an ordering in the SQL query itself using `ORDER BY` or put them into an array in PHP and reverse the array:

```
$all_rows = array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result3)) {
  $all_rows[] = $row;
}

$all_rows = array_reverse($all_rows);
```

Answer (score 0):

Order your fields with the `ORDER BY` sql feature. So choose what field you want to order by, and order it by that field..

```
$result3=mysql_query("select * from $mail ORDER BY date DESC ,time DESC");
```

or if they have an id field:

```
$result3=mysql_query("select * from $mail ORDER BY id DESC");
```

And while you're at it, make sure that you know EXCATLY what is in `$mail`!

Comment: It looks like someone has downvoted *all* answers to this question within a couple of seconds. Strange behavior Not sure how to go about with that (not that I am affected). +1 from me.

Comment: As avada said, looks like a serial downvote. Go to meta.stackoverflow.com and search for the tag [serial-downvotes], it'll probably be cleared automatically if that was indeed the case.

Answer (score -1):

```
"select * from $mail order by date DESC, time DESC"
```